# iptables search in web content

Tags: iptables, http, content-filter

How can I set an iptables rule (ex:in input chain) that check the http packet's content and block that contain my html or css or javascript code?
For example: block sites that return in their response

```
<div id="helloworld"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string match module e.g.

```
 iptables -I INPUT -m string --string '<div id="helloworld"></div>' -j DROP
```

Comment: I tested with both bm and kmp algoritms.Not work!

Answer (score 0):

iptables (user-space tool) or netfilter (Linux firewall) is not designed to filter HTTP content. Anyway, you can use `string` module to match a specific value in the packet payload.

A better approach is to redirect HTTP traffic to a proxy server like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and do the filtering / caching and whatever you want. Please, note that squid by itself does not support content filtering using ACL. You need to use another software that supports filtering such as [dansguardian](http://dansguardian.org/).

Comment: I have squid as transparent proxy.How can I do that by squid?

Comment: @Addr3ss: Squid by itself does not have an ACL type to filter based on content. You need to use another software. See my updated answer